# MultiValueDictKeyError in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

UPDATE

**model:**

```
class PicturesManager(models.Manager):
    def create_pictures(self, flat, img):
        pictures = self.create(car=car, image=img)
        return pictures

def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), filename.split('.')[-1])
    return os.path.join('car_img/', filename)

class Pictures(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, verbose_name="Car Image", related_name='pictures')
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Photo", upload_to = get_file_path, max_length=64)
    objects = PicturesManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**admin:**

```
class MyInlineModelAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Pictures
    extra = 3
class CarOptionsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CarOptions

class WatchesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Watches

class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CarOptionsInline, WatchesInline, MyInlineModelAdmin]
```

When I edit Car in admin, I have error: **MultiValueDictKeyError at ... "u'pictures-0-id'"**

**Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin1/cars/car/1/

Django Version: 1.6c1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'cars',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  430.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  339.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1227.             if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in all_valid
  415.         if not formset.is_valid():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in is_valid
  292.         err = self.errors
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in errors
  267.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in full_clean
  314.             form = self.forms[i]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  49.         res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in forms
  133.         forms = [self._construct_form(i) for i in xrange(self.total_form_count())]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _construct_form
  839.         form = super(BaseInlineFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _construct_form
  555.             pk = self.data[pk_key]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  301.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin1/cars/car/1/
Exception Value: "u'pictures-0-id'"
```

How to fix it? I use Django 1.6c1.

Thanks!

Comment: show us `CarOptionsInline, WatchesInline, MyInlineModelAdmin` models

Comment: was that error after add the `inline`s?

Comment: @lalo Tabular or inline - the same error

Comment: I install sorl-thumbnail, the same error

Comment: The error appears if I add or change image. Object without image works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: update admin template.

Comment: delete old, install new

Comment: Are you saying "upgrade your version of django", or some other suggestion?   IE From where are you recommending to get a new admin template that works?

Comment: Yep - the original answer isn't really helpful but Daniel's is!

Answer (score 19):

I think it is related to a Django 1.6 ticket

[#ticket 13696 -- ensured inline pk field is rendered](https://github.com/kmtracey/django/commit/9e5519f50536288db2ae0c6fa4b95193788dfb7a)

You have to update the following admin templates:

- stacked.html
- tabular.html

Remove the single line:

```
{% if inline_admin_form.has_auto_field %}{{ inline_admin_form.pk_field.field }}{% endif %}
```

and add the lines:

```
{% if inline_admin_form.needs_explicit_pk_field %}
    {{ inline_admin_form.pk_field.field }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the second code block solved my issue with a custom template override; my template was out of date after upgrading to 1.10

Comment: That's happening on the django 1.11 too.

Answer (score 13):

If you are already on a newer version of django and still get this, make sure your non-AutoField PK has "editable=False" in the model definition.

Comment: YES! this fixed it, tried many super complicated solutions and this was it. Thanks

Comment: Fixed my issue with Django 1.10.  Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately this prevents DRF from being able to create the object properly, lekaing the custom PK blank.

Answer (score 2):

For Django <= 1.7.3, also make sure, that the primary key field of your inline model is an AutoField:

**wrong:**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

**correct:**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

See
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15665

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was update grappelli to 2.5.1 (assuming you are using grappelli ofc). I assume this is because it performs the specified admin template updates.

```
pip install django-grappelli==2.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using django-suit. You do need to update `django-suit` version to the most recent one compatible with your django version. In my case, I was using `django 1.10` and updated django-suit from `0.2.25 -> 0.2.28`.

`pip install django-suit==0.2.28`